# An error occurred while LULC raster converting into Vector in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

[image: error description, NoneType object has no attribute setColor]

[The error depicts above come again and again while converting land cover classification raster into vector shapefile in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/404).

In semi automatic classification plugin, there is an option to check `Create vector` which may help you to convert the classification from raster to vector. However, the problem :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set Color'

came again and again.

Comment: Maybe kind of related : https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues/48